# Reading Text Boxes in Visual Studios Express 2012 for Windows 8

Tags: javascript, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a Windows 8 app, and I am trying to read text boxes with numbers. I first attempted to use the "Hello World" example that Microsoft provides to read text boxes, but I ran a few tests, and the text boxes are not being read, it returns as "null."

When I have:

```
 var userName = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
```

it works in the HelloWorld example.

When I use the same code, but altered in my app:

```
 var amount = document.getElementById("Amount").value;
```

the app has an error at the line above. When I remove the ".value" I get "null" but no error.

How am I able to read the input in a text box in Microsoft Visual Studios for Windows 8, using java script, without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried debugging? If you set a breakpoint (F9) on your "var amount..." line and then debug your app (F5), you should break there and then be able to use the JavaScript console pane in VS2012 to try things. See if you're able to do `document.getElementById("Amount")` there. You should. Your code looks right. Do you have "Amount" as the id of your textbox? If you set it as the name of your textbox then getElementById won't work to select it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried below as u needed..i hope u will get idea.

```
<script>
    function callfunction()
    {
        var item = document.getElementById("total").value;
        alert(item);
    }
</script>
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" maxlength="60"> amount
<input type="button" onclick="callfunction();" />
```

Comment: The value is what is giving me the error. Also, the HTML is not on the same page in Visual Studios, but I tried to add some of this individually. The issue I am having is where ".value" is causing my app to crash. Without the ".value" the app does not crash, but the text box is not read and the values stored, it gives an output of "null."